# Recursively print all the nodes in a tree in java

Tags: java, tree

I want to print out everything in a tree (not a binary tree) from left to right. I have the following tree class and its methods:

```
public class Tree
{
    Node root;

    public Tree(String rootData) 
    {
        root = new Node();
        root.data = rootData;
        root.children = new ArrayList<Node>();
    }

    public static class Node
    {
        private String data;
        private Node parent;
        private List<Node> children;

        public Node(){}

        public Node(String newNodeData, Node newNodeParent)
        {
            data = newNodeData;
            parent = newNodeParent;
        }
    }

    public void print(Node curNode)
    {
        int index = 0;
        while(curNode.children.get(index) != null)
        {
            print(curNode.children.get(index));
            System.out.println(curNode.children.get(index).data);
        }
    }
```

It throws a Null Pointer Exception at the `print(curNode.childred.get(index));` line and I dont quite understand why. When `print` is first called, the tree's root node is passed to it. Am I oversimplifying the print method, or is there a generally better way to do this? Everything i've found online was for binary search trees and I couldnt figure out how to make it apply to this.

I also am open to doing this iteratively, but I wouldn't know where to start with that, and I know it would be way more complex then doing it recursively. Or if i'm wrong in saying so let me know.

Comment: A full trace of the error output would be useful :)

Comment: You're getting a NPE because something is `null`.  You should use the debugger to figure out which thing that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `Node(String newNodeData, Node newNodeParent)` constructor does not initialize children, hence its null. you only ever initialize the children array for the root node.

also, when iteratin over children, either compare index to children.getSize() or switch to the newer `for(Node n : children)` syntax

as a final sidenote - youre accessing Node filds from the Tree constructor. direct field access from a different class is generally frowned upon in java.